# Make tracking codes disappear from URL bar

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, analytics

I'm using tracking codes to know where do the visitors of my website come from.

Example:

- Facebook "Use App" button http://www.example.com/?fb_useapp=1
- An emailing campaign : http://www.example.com/?mailingjuly2017=1
- etc.

But then this is what gets displayed in the browser:

[image]

This is not very user-friendly: the users shouldn't see this information. **How to get this parameter hidden on browser?** (but still present in the server logs, that's where I'll do my analysis!)

Shoud I do it from JS or PHP, or even in an `.htaccess` `RewriteRule`?

PS: instead of using parameters `?param=1`, I could also use a different approach and have a RewriteRule redirect `example.com/mailingjuly2017/` to `example.com`.

Comment: Process the Data and redirect the User to a clean Url.

Comment: @Bernhard How? Should I create a dedicated HTML file for every of these links and include a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />` (this seems to be discouraged by W3C)? Will this result in a HTTP 302 Redirection? Isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: Do it with PHP. Catch the GET-Parameters and then you can do a header('location: ...');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the appearance of the parameters in the address bar without the need to refresh the page, you can try the following JS:

```
if (history.pushState && window.location.href.includes('?')) {
    history.pushState({}, null, window.location.origin);
}
```

This will remove the parameters in url address bar and should not affect server-side logs.  Note that it will also remove them in the history so if the user clicks the back button and then forward, the page will be loaded without the parameters.  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for details and browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks! I Would this be considered as a good practice (this would really delete any parameter from address bar, wouldn't it?)? I imagine such request is very common for people using ads, wanting to track conversions. What is the "official recommended" way?

Comment: As written in the example, it would strip out all parameters, but you can do any string manipulation you like to the third parameter in the call to `history.pushState` (the 'new' url) and could just remove specific url parameters.  There is a restriction according to MDN: _The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception._